# Update the JSON for dropdown when one of the drop down values is selected and show the new options in primeNG TreeSelect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I have a tree like data coming from rest API, at root level I get only the root nodes and link to their child nodes. If we want to get the value of its child node then I will make another rest call. so on and so forth. To display such data I am using primng treeselect component. Looking at their documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13-lts/#/treeselect I found that they provide an event "onNodeExpand", my plan was to make rest call on every "onNodeExpand" and bring the child nodes, append it in options JSON and display the childnode. With this approach when I am trying to append new data in options JSON then it is throwing exception `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')`. I am using angular 13

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { NodeService } from './nodeservice';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface ChildNode {
  children: Child[];
}

interface Child {
  label: string;
  icon: string;
  data: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  styles: [
    `
      :host ::ng-deep .p-treeselect {
          width:20rem;
          display: inline-flex;
      }
  `,
  ],
  providers: [MessageService],
})
export class AppComponent {
  nodes3: any[];

  selectedNodes2: any[] = [];

  selectedNode: any;

  obj: any;

  constructor(public nodeService: NodeService, private http: HttpClient) {
    let jsonObj =
      '{"children":[{"label":"Work","data":"Work Folder","expandedIcon":"pi pi-folder-open","collapsedIcon":"pi pi-folder"},{"label":"Home","data":"Home Folder","expandedIcon":"pi pi-folder-open","collapsedIcon":"pi pi-folder"}]}';

    this.obj = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.nodeService.getFiles().then((files) => (this.nodes3 = files));
  }

  onDropDownClick(event) {
    // console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event);
    event.node.children.forEach((obj) => {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        console.log('children present');
      } else {
        console.log(obj);
        this.nodes3['children'][0] = this.obj;
      }
    });
  }
}


/* below is sample json I am working with */

/*
{
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Parent Asset",
      "data": "Parent Asset Folder",
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "Child Asset",
          "data": "Child Asset Folder"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h5>With filter</h5>
  <p-treeSelect
    [(ngModel)]="selectedNodes2"
    [options]="nodes3"
    selectionMode="single"
    placeholder="Select a Node"
    [filter]="true"
    (onNodeExpand)="onDropDownClick($event)"
  ></p-treeSelect>
</div>
```